# Apache not loading CSS files on remote browsers but works on localhost

Tags: apache

I have an ubuntu installation on my laptop i use for web app development. When i type in http://localhost/blah.php i see my php web page as i normally would with all css style loaded and rendering fine.

When i try to connect to this same apache server from a remote machine by typing in the IP address the page loads but without any css styling at all. I also get the same problem trying to connect to the apache server from a virtual machine on the same box. I would like to get this working so i can test my web apps in IE but obviously css not loading is a problem. Any tips ?

Comment: Have you looked at the apache access logs?

Comment: What happens if you try to access the CSS style sheet directly in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your source code and look how your style sheets are referenced.

If you have references to `http://localhost/mystylesheet.css`, that's your problem right there.

If that doesn't help, try to access a style sheet directly (enter the address in the browser) and tell us what happens. Also post the URL you are using. The head of the HTML document you are calling would also be helpful.