# linking to css in localhost getting lost in multiple pages

Tags: php, css, xampp, localhost

I just recently installed XAMPP and have been trying to get my former website which was hosted online to work in it.

Everythings okay until I navigate past my baseurl.  To make matters a bit more complicated, i've been the page using jquery-mobile so all the content is fetched through AJAX.

baseurl = 127.0.0.1/mobilebrowsergame/

When I refresh(start) on this page, everythings okay because it uses the default root for the CSS files.

However, if I start/refresh on a page a bit deeper, ie.

127.0.0.1/mobilebrowsergame/structure/1

The css obviously doesnt work.

I originally included `<?php echo base_url() ?>css/stylesheet.css ?>` but was forced to remove the base_url() because it wasn't loading under localhost.

At this point, I'm at a loss.  I don't know how to tackle this without creating a new CSS for ever page under the base.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using mod_rewrite? the function base_url() has what code in it?

Comment: Note, it would work if base url also contained a protocol, e.g. http://.  Without a protocol, any link is assumed relative.  Fix that, and you'd fix your issue and you could go back to using base_url (which I would recommend you do!)

Comment: base_url() is from a codeigniter function i believe.  Regardless, It removed it from the code I was currently working in based on the suggestion found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304029/apache-not-loading-css-files-on-remote-browsers-but-works-on-localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are pointing to your CSS files using a relative URL. If you prepend a path with `/`, it will automatically start at the web serve root (in this case, `127.0.0.1`), instead of at the current directory.

i.e. Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mobilebrowsergame/css/stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: That is correct. by using the `/` as the first character, you as declaring a relative path within your domain instead of an absolute one. which means no need to declare your website name in the link. =)

Comment: Thank you, was SO hoping for an easy solution.